# VBA copy row to another worksheet but stops on 10th row then stays on row 1

Tags: excel, vba, datatables, copy-paste, named-ranges

In this work sheet I want to copy from intersected row from the chemicals tab to the Bill of Lading Tab.  It works fine for rows 10-19(worksheet) (1-10 in the range).  Then it selects row 1 in the range and stays there.  It continus to copy and paste into that row.

Original copy range is wsh Chemicals active row D:M
Destination is wsh Bill of Lading tbl BILLLAD whish is wsh range A10(first data row) to J27.
My current code is as follows.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, 
    Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim thisRow As Long
    Dim nwSh As Worksheet
    Dim newRow As Long

    Set nwSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Bill of Lading")
    newRow = nwSh.UsedRange.Rows(nwSh.Range("a9:j27").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    thisRow = ActiveCell.Row
    Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, Range("d:m")).Copy Sheets("Bill of Lading").Range("a" & newRow)


    'MsgBox nwSh.UsedRange.Rows(nwSh.Range("a9:j27").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

The destinitation is a Table.  I tried to return it to a range but no luck.  I revied the code (its an old workbook that I am updating) and do not see any other code that would be interfering.

This whole project has been beating me pretty bad.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Presumptions:

1. It looks like you are calling this procedure by clicking on a cell in the row you want to copy and then double clicking on that cell.
2. You start with a blank Bill of Lading worksheet. There are probably headers in row 9.
3. Your expectation is that cells D:M of the active row will be copied into cells A:J starting on row 10 & continuing down.

Your problem is with this line:

```
newRow = nwSh.UsedRange.Rows(nwSh.Range("a9:j27").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
```

This section will always return a value of 19 (27 - 9 + 1 = 19):

```
nwSh.Range("a9:j27").Rows.Count
```

So, every time you run the code, it starts with UsedRange.Rows(19), then .End(xlUp).Offset(1).

The first time you run it, xlUp will take you to Row 9, the offset takes you to 10.
Second time takes you to Row 10, offset to 11.
Continuing, when you get to the 9th time, the xlUp will take you to 17, offset goes to 18.
Then on the 10th time, xlUp to 18, offset to 19, and you populate that cell.

Now, on the 11th and subsequent times, you are still starting with row 19, but it is populated, as are all of the cells above it. So xlUp will take you all the way up to Row 9, offset to Row 10, and will continue to populate Row 10.

An easy workaround would be to change

```
nwSh.Range("a9:j27").Rows.Count
```

to be

```
Rows.Count
```

assuming there is nothing below your data.

Hope this helps. Let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: I do have info in the cells below that range.  Could I use your fix and have it give me a msg such as Bill of Lading Full?